# How to capture screen using a private API in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-recording

I was the developer for an app called iCapture now known as iProRec which was a non jailbroken screen recorder that made its way on the App Store. I know how to record using airplay mirroring and I want to see if it is possible to do the same but with no wifi. I know it will use private API but I'm just curious to know if it is possible still with iOS 10 frameworks. What would be the best place to start?

Answer (score 1):

No, Apple has closed off IOMobileFrameBuffer and the previous private framework used for capturing device screen after the 9.3.3 jailbreak. Now you really have a single option and that would be using the AirPlay protocol to "record" the devices screen.